# What does this type of "division summation" notation mean?

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-number-theory, notation

> $$\sum_{p | k} f(p)$$

What does this type of summation actually mean?
Can you give me an example(s) with $p=1, 2$?

Answer (score 3):

$\sum_{p | k} f(p)$ : This notation basically denotes the sum of the functional values $f$ of all the $p$'s which divide a given $k$. $k \in \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: The $p$ is probably meant to stand for the prime divisors of $k$ - the context will make that clear.

Comment: @EthanBolker Yeah, you're right.